# ssrs expression to calculate number of worked days in particular month

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i need to calculate the number of worked days in a particular month. i have start date and end date depending on this i have to calculate the worked days in particular month. in ssrs report please help me with a ssrs expression to solve the problem.

i have a logic to do this but how to do it in a SSRS expression is a problem.

the logic is:

if(start date is in January than
         start date-31/1/2014)
         //this will give me the worked days in January

if(start date is not in January
         start date-1/1/2014    //this gives me working days till January
         (total working days)-( start date-1/1/2014)//this gives me working days after January 1
if((total working days)-( start date-1/1/2014)>31
    then my answer is 31 days worked in January.

i have to convert this logic in to ssrs expression, is it possible?

is there any alternate way to do this ?

please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you're using for your dataset? It sounds like you could just add one more field with a CASE statement or DATEDIFF function.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic at all? I'm not sure which bits are parameters and which are calculations - it looks like you have an `Date Parameter` and you want to calculate the difference in days between this`date parameter` and a `Working Start Date` field, but only count days that fall in the same month as the `Date Parameter`. Is that it?